# How can I use SwiftUI ScrollView to scroll beyond the ScrollView frame, to allow the scrolling content to display under header/foot views?

Tags: swiftui

I have a header and foot on a ZStack and in the middle I have a ScrollView with content. This keeps the indicators visible in the middle portion, however it also means that the content inside the ScrollView does not extend to the header and footer, as seen in many apps with a blur effect. Is there any way currently to have the ScrollView extend its content beyond its frame?

```
import SwiftUI




struct ContentView: View {

    var fullyUnder: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<50) { _ in
                        Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.red).frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    }
                }
            }

            VStack {
                Color.green.opacity(0.50).frame(height: 30)
                Spacer()
                Color.blue.opacity(0.50).frame(height: 30)
            }


        }
    }

    var fullyIn: some View {
        VStack {
            Color.green.opacity(0.50).frame(height: 30)

            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<50) { _ in
                        Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.red).frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    }
                }
            }

            Color.blue.opacity(0.50).frame(height: 30)

        }
    }


    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            // This shows the content under the header/footer but the indicator also goes under
            fullyUnder

            Divider()

            // This shows the indicator properly, but the content doesn't go udner the header/footer
            fullyIn

        }
    }


}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: please show us your code (should be compilable and reproduce the error). this is a "we help you with your code"-platform, not a "we write code for free for you"-platform. and please read and consider this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sure, but I think the question is clear. It’s not a code question, it’s “does ScrollView have this ability”.

Comment: thank you for showing your code, but your question in the caption is another question than in text. in caption you ask for scrollview going under footer/header, which you answer already in your text - yes it is possible. your question in the text is about the scroll indicators - which is not possible in swiftui. but you could do it with scrollIndicatorInsets with uiviewrepresentable, but scrollIndicatorInsets is deprecated...

Comment: I don't agree. The question is very clear. It asks how to scroll the content BEYOND the scroll frame, which is exactly what I show cannot be done.

Comment: FYI, my [UIKit-based solution](https://github.com/jtbandes/space-pics) handles this okay. I believe UIScrollViews by default do not have clipsToBounds enabled.